# how to do clustering when I have multiple categorical column and less number of numerical column in pandas?

Tags: pandas, encoding, data-science, cluster-analysis, k-means

[image]

Say I have one column (X) which holds the customer id and have other multiple columns x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6
which have only these 4 distinct values ('High','Low','Medium','Nan') repeatedly. Please click on the above the attachment

Recent update: 16/12/2021: I have done one hot encoding and got 19 features now along with X column now I need to know how to go ahead with the clustering part for such unsupervised data set

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you expect?

Comment: I need to create cluster based on this data. Pls look into the screenshot

Comment: I have done one hot encoding and got 19 features now along with id column now I need to know how to ho ahead with the clustering part for such unsupervised data set

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question what encoding to use i found this article to give a good understanding of when to use label encoding or one hot encoding:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/03/one-hot-encoding-vs-label-encoding-using-scikit-learn/

In your case as you do have a ordinal value of your data (high > medium > low > nan) i would suggest using the label encoding technique.

Then regarding the clusteringpart you have identified three diffrent clusters, do you want to identify which samples belong to which cluster or what is your goal?
You could start train a model with 3 cluster centroids as you have identified yourself but could also use an elbow function to find a optimal number of clusters to your dataset. (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/elbow-method-for-optimal-value-of-k-in-kmeans/)

---

For label encoding on a column in your dataframe:

```
encoding_dict = {}
def label_encode(string_value):
   num_value = encoding_dict.setdefault(string_value, len(encoding_dict)) # Sets a numerical value for your string value
   return num_value

for col in dataframe.columns:
    if dataframe[col].dtype == object: #indicates string
        dataframe[col] = dataframe[col].apply(label_encode)
        encoding_dict = {} # Reset encoding dict to not reuse same values (or dont if you always have same values)
```

Comment: I need to identify which sample belongs to which cluster. Will try to implement one-hot encoding for all such columns initially

Comment: I'll update my answer to include code for label encoding if you change your mind.

Comment: I have done the one-hot encoding and now I need to know how to do the clustering for that

Comment: You'll find the documentation with examples here: 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html?highlight=kmeans#sklearn.cluster.KMeans

If you find my examples and comments to be of help, please do give up (or down) -votes to increase awareness and give me feedback!

Comment: In all the blogs and videos I watch I can see a target column but in my scenario I dnt have target value and it is an unsupervised data set so I need to do clustering without target column

Comment: If you follow the example on:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html?highlight=kmeans#sklearn.cluster.KMeans

and only follow it until the row where it uses the `.fit()` function, then you have a trained model without the use of labels. They use labels in the example to verify the results of the predictions of the model. You may have to think about if you have no labels at all, how to verify the validity of the clusters.